# Ошибка Could not initialize class org.apache.tools.zip.ExtraFieldUtils при запуске нового проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Создал новый проект в андроид студии, но он создаётся с ошибкой. Вот что пишет в консоли грейдла:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library'.
> Could not initialize class org.apache.tools.zip.ExtraFieldUtils

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.11 secs
```

Почему-то теперь такая ошибка возникает при создании любого нового проекта. Как это устранить?

Comment: какие то проблемы с интеграцией  в проект AnimatedVectorDrawable. Так происходит с дефолтными шаблонами или вашими проектами? неплохо приложить к вопросу build.gradle модуля приложения.

Comment: Со старыми проектами этого не происходит, только при создании новых. Но проблему уже решил, обновив студию до последней версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил Android Studio до последней версии (2.3.1) и всё вроде бы прошло.